# How to format column to number format in Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the VBA code.  Sheet2 contains all of the values in general format.  After running the code, values in column 'C' of Sheet3 contain exponential values for numbers which are 13 or more digits.

What should be done so that column 'C' of Sheet3 does not contain exponential values?

```
private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i, j, k As Variant

 k = 1
For i = 1 To 30000
If Sheet2.Range("c" & i).Value >= 100 And Sheet2.Range("c" & i).Value < 1000 Then
Sheet3.Range("a" & k).Value = Sheet2.Range("a" & i).Value
Sheet3.Range("b" & k).Value = Sheet2.Range("b" & i).Value

Sheet3.Range("c" & k).Value = Sheet2.Range("c" & i).Value

k = k + 1
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: please explain some more. You just want to format numbers in certain column or what?

Comment: yes want to format required column only

Comment: I don't see this at 13 but rather at the 15th digit. Do you want the result for display or to do math on? is saving as a text string and converting to a value to use it possible?

Comment: openoffice may not have have the 15 digit limitation

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This will format column A as text, B as General, C as a number.

```
Sub formatColumns()
 Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@"
 Columns(2).NumberFormat = "General"
 Columns(3).NumberFormat = "0"
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this for a particular sheet in a specific workbook by `Workbooks("B.xlsm").ActiveSheet.Columns("1").NumberFormat = "0"` & this doesnt seem to do it for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If your 13 digit "number" is really text, that is you don't intend to do any math on it, you can precede it with an apostrophe

```
Sheet3.Range("c" & k).Value = "'" & Sheet2.Range("c" & i).Value
```

But I don't see how a 13 digit number would ever get past the If statement because it would always be greater than 1000.  Here's an alternate version

```
Sub CommandClick()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rNext As Range

    For Each rCell In Sheet2.Range("C1:C30000").Cells
        If rCell.Value >= 100 And rCell.Value < 1000 Then
            Set rNext = Sheet3.Cells(Sheet3.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            rNext.Resize(1, 3).Value = rCell.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 3).Value
        End If
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NON SMTF").Columns("C:C").NumberFormat = "@"
use this working proper

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bump an old question but the answer is to count the character length of the cell and not its value.

```
CellCount = Cells(Row, 10).Value
If Len(CellCount) <= "13" Then
'do something
End If
```

hope that helps. Cheers