# Formatting number to have commas in exporting to excel

Tags: java, export-to-excel, number-formatting

I'd like to take a number, say `123456`, and I'd like to format it as `123,456.00` when exporting to Excel through a Java app. I need it to be treated as a number in order to perform numeric calculations in Excel.

Comment: Are you writing your own export facility or using an existing one like Apache POI?

Comment: using own export facility

Comment: Can you export the number as 123456 and have it formatted later? The commas and decimal points are really syntactic sugar.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752137/how-to-format-column-to-number-format-in-excel-sheet to tell Excel how to format the numbers.

Comment: My application users want to see 123456 as 123,456.00 and have numeric calculations on the field when it downloaded :) trying for that.

Comment: Can you suggest how that can be done using Apache POI?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

I would suggest that you implement this using a well known Excel API, Apache POI. Here is the [Getting Started](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) page.

If you want to format your numeric cell with commas, please see this section of the [Quick Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DataFormats).

Comment: Thank you so much rajah!. Quick Guide helped and I could complete the task.