# Find Column Header By Name And Select All Data Below Column Header

Tags: excel, vba

I copied this code from this post :
[stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686841/find-column-header-by-name-and-select-all-data-below-column-header-excel-vba)

```
Sub FindColumn()
  Dim rngAddress As Range
  Set rngAddress = Range("A1:BZ1").Find("STVCNTY CODE Mailing")
  If rngAddress Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "STVCNTY CODE Mailing column was not found."
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Range(rngAddress, rngAddress.End(xlDown)).Select
End Sub
```

I seems to work except for one problem, it stops the 'select' when it encounters a empty cell.  see pic
[image: stops select short]

how can modify this code to select the entire column and change format to 000?

I have this done already thinking the column I was looking for was static but now I'm told the column position will vary by report  i.e it be in column AN on Mondays report , be in column BA on tuesday, etc.

here is the simple code I already had:

```
' formats column to 000

Columns("AN:AN").Select

Selection.NumberFormat = "000"
```

Any help would be apprecaited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Go the bottom of the column and work up (no need to Select either).

```
Sub FindColumn()

Dim rngAddress As Range

Set rngAddress = Range("A1:BZ1").Find("STVCNTY CODE Mailing")
If rngAddress Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "STVCNTY CODE Mailing column was not found."
  Exit Sub
End If

'just used range
Range(rngAddress, Cells(Rows.Count, rngAddress.Column).End(xlUp)).NumberFormat = "000"

'OR entire column
rngAddress.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "000"

Range(rngAddress.Offset(1), rngAddress.Offset(199)).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & rngAddress.Offset(1, -1).Address(0, 0) & ",[CountyCodes2.xlsm]Sheet1!CountyTable,2,FALSE),"""")"

End Sub
```

Comment: your code seems to work.  Do I have to use one or the other of the last lines of your code?  or can both be used together?

Comment: 2nd question if I may.  I had another line in the code that performed a VLOOKUP based on where that header was:  ' performs VLOOKUP
Range("AN2:AN200").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(AM2,[CountyCodes2.xlsm]Sheet1!CountyTable,2,FALSE),"""")"
 how do I modify the Range to use the column that your code found the header ?    The AM2 is supposed to be next to the column that was being searched for previously.  wish I could attach pic in these comments to show you but I cant

Comment: I think the first is probably preferable as otherwise you are formatting all million cells which is probably unnecessary. Re the lookup I've added a line to the code which I think does what you want (assuming it should refer to the column to the left of rngAddress.