# Through VBA - How to find a specific column by name say Inception_Month

Tags: excel, vba

Through VBA - How to find a specific column by name say Inception_Month and if found delete entire column and if not found, go ahead with the remaining code. Please help guys.

I already tried this by recording a macro by doing Ctrl F but it gives error if it doesn't find a particular column name, I don't want to see the error. I want the code to continue with next steps if no column exists by name "Inception_Month".

If Column name is found - I want the entire column to be removed  and right next column to be moved at the deleted column space, don't want to see an empty column.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried.  Then go to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686841/find-column-header-by-name-and-select-all-data-below-column-header-excel-vba  and look at the second solution  (or google >vba excel find column name<)

Answer (score 0):

You can go to insert make it a table and then you can use something like the below.

```
MyTableName.HeaderRowRange.Cells.Find("Inception_Month").Delete
```

Or use something like below

```
Sub Find_Column()
Dim ws as ActiveSheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    Set c = .Find("Inception_Month", LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        ' some code here
    else
        Columns(c.Column).Delete
    End If
End With
End Sub
```