# Change Column Number formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I'm copying columns from one spreadsheet to another:

```
Set sourceColumn = wb.Worksheets(cmb).Columns(wb.Sheets(cmb).Rows(1).Find(Form.ComboBox2.Value).Column)
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("B.xlsm").ActiveSheet.Columns("A")
sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
```

After copying, I want to convert the number formatting of the targetColumn to number. 
In reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752137/how-to-format-column-to-number-format-in-excel-sheet) post, I tried `Workbooks("B.xlsm").ActiveSheet.Columns("1").NumberFormat = "0"` but that isnt changing the column formatting from text to number.

Any ideas whats going awry?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that all values on your column are numbers formatted as text, you can try *[Text to Column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-texttocolumns-method-excel)* functionality like:

```
With Workbooks("B.xlsm").ActiveSheet ' you might want to be more explicit here
    .Columns(1).TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns(1), _
                              DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                              FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1)
End With
```

Above changes the column 1 format to *General* which will make all entries that looks like a number to number format.

Comment: This still stores the column entry as text. How do I typecast it to number?

Comment: @user248884 You execute this after copying the contents.

Comment: @user248884 And all your date is in Column 1 (A)? It should work as long as your entry are numbers entered as text. Can you show actual sample data so I can test?